Is it bad practice to wrap everything in a try...catch block?
I often wrap entire functions in try...catch blocks where the catch section prints the error stack (and sends me an email about it) if I didn't catch a bug before deployment. Is this bad practice? Here's an example endpoint:
    app.get('/api/get-furniture', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const query = 
        `SELECT Clase.nombre AS clase, Grupo.nombre AS grupo, Subgrupo.nombre AS subgrupo
        FROM Subgrupo
        JOIN Grupo ON Subgrupo.grupo_id = Grupo.id
        JOIN Clase ON Grupo.clase_id = Clase.id;`;
        // cast Class Name to "Clase", Group Name to "Grupo", and Subgroup Name to "Subgrupo"
        // start from Subgrupo table
        // join Grupo table on Subgrupo's grupo_id
        // join Clase table on Grupo's clase_id

        const result = await dbRequest(query); // get furniture data from database

        const data = {};
        result.forEach((row) => {
            if (!data[row.clase]) data[row.clase] = {}; // if class doesn't exist in data, create it
            if (!data[row.clase][row.grupo]) data[row.clase][row.grupo] = []; // if group doesn't exist in class, create it
            data[row.clase][row.grupo].push(row.subgrupo); // add subgroup to group
        });

        res.json(data); // send furniture data
    }
    catch (error) {
        errorEmail('Endpoint get-furniture', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }
});


It should be the job of app to return a 500 error if anything goes wrong in any of your handlers. It should be the job of a global error handler to log errors. It should be the job of some log monitoring system to send you alerts when errors are logged. You should not make this error handling strategy repeatedly part of every single function. Most of all, you'll want different error handling strategies in different environments, so hardcoding sending an email is a bad idea.

@deceze is app.use((err, req, res, next) => { errorEmail(req.path, err); res.status(500).send('Internal server error'); });
fine? and then just do next(error);?

You can create an Error handler class that will be responsible for this. Instead of using try and catch in all the class.

Don't know why you are down-voted, you are absolutely right. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html It's in the docs, under Writing error handlers

@SilviuBurcea Maybe, because it doesn't answer the questions: "Is it bad practice to wrap everything in a try...catch block?" and "Is this bad practice?". IMO, it's not even a useful comment. The OP didn't ask for an alternative.

@jabaa Suggesting a much better way of handling exceptions, even listed in the docs!, implies that OP is doing something that's not advised.

@SilviuBurcea If it's bad practice, the answer should explain, why it's bad practice and why the alternative is technically better, not only an opinion. If it's not bad practice for technical reasons, this is a bad answer.
